# Showing markers programmatically

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to (programmatically) make a certain `IMarker` be shown in the problem view, similar to what happens when the user selects "View in..." from the context menu? I have a wizard which may cause markers to appear, and I would like to make these markers visible in the problem view when the wizard is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to make your markers to be problems. However there are separate Markers view that shows all the markers.

To show marker you can use [MarkerViewUtil.showMarker(..)](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/views/markers/MarkerViewUtil.html#showMarker%28org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage,%20org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker,%20boolean%29)

Comment: The markers *are* problems, and they are visible in the view as long as the user *navigates* to them. But I want to forcibly make them visible in the view, for example making the problem view expand the "Errors" and/or "Warnings" nodes.

Comment: I've added note about corresponding API.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all good API rules, you could look into the internals of FiltersConfigurationDialog to create a new resource filter in the problems view programmatically. But I repeat: there is no API for creating problems filters and this might then break at any time.